# Speeding up calls on MethodInfo

Tags: c#, reflection

I have implemented a compiler and virtual machine for a language. The implementation is in C# and the stack-based VM uses reflection to make function calls on a set of built-ins.

Much of the code involves simply pushing and popping stack values, but the workhorse is the function call. Currently the implementation of a function call looks like this:

```
      var calli = gencode[pc++] as CallInfo;
      var calla = PopStackList(calli.NumArgs).ToArray();
      var ret = calli.MethodInfo.Invoke(instance, calla);
      if (ret != null) PushStack(ret);
```

All data items passed and returned are objects using a custom type system (no native types used). Clarification: this is an instance method, not static.

Performance testing suggests that this `MethodInfo.Invoke` is quite slow. The question is how to make function calls at the highest possible speed, presumably by doing more preparatory work in the compiler and generating better code.

---

In response to suggestions, one possibility is to create a delegate. Unfortunately as far as I can tell a delegate has to be bound to a specific instance of a class, or to a static method, and creating a delegate after creating the instance rather defeats the purpose.

I see a vote to close, but to my eye the question is not broad at all. How should a compiler implement functions calls on instance methods in a virtual machine for best performance, at the very least faster than `MethodInfo.Invoke()`?

Comment: Consider using code generation (`Expression` is great for this) instead of reflection.

Comment: A few years ago, `IKVM.Reflection` was created as an alternative, but discontinued recently by its main developer. As Microsoft has open sourced .NET Core, you might also check their opinion on the performance side by creating a discussion at corefx repo, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues

Comment: @LexLi: Thanks, worth looking into. I'll probably put off bothering corefx people until I've tried the compiling thing.

Comment: You already have the VM.  Consider generating IL instead so you can take advantage of the jitter.

Comment: @HansPassant: [hello again] Last time I used Reflection.Emit (15 years ago) I didn't enjoy the experience. Is there an easier way now? Via Expression maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to convert MethodInfo.Invoke to delegate:

Normally when you’re calling methods with reflection, you call MethodInfo.Invoke. Unfortunately, this proves to be quite slow. If you know the signature of the method at compile-time, you can convert the method into a delegate with that signature using Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, object, MethodInfo). You simply pass in the delegate type you want to create an instance of, the target of the call (i.e. what the method will be called on), and the method you want to call. It would be nice if there were a generic version of this call to avoid casting the result, but never mind. Here’s a complete example demonstrating how it works:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = (string).GetMethod(“IndexOf”, new Type[]{typeof(char)});

        Func<char, int> converted = (Func<char, int>) 
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<char, int>), “Hello”, method);

        Console.WriteLine(converted(‘l’));
        Console.WriteLine(converted(‘o’));
        Console.WriteLine(converted(‘x’));
    }
}
```

This prints out 2, 4, and -1; exactly what we’d get if we’d called "Hello".IndexOf(...) directly. Now let’s see what the speed differences are…

We’re mostly interested in the time taken to go from the main calling code to the method being called, whether that’s with a direct method call, MethodInfo.Invoke or the delegate. To make IndexOf itself take as little time as possible, I tested it by passing in ‘H’ so it would return 0 immediately. As normal, the test was rough and ready, but here are the results:

Invocation type Stopwatch ticks per invocation
Direct  0.18
Reflection  120
Delegate    0.20

Copied from: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Comment: If anyone knows i would like to know why this becomes faster.

Comment: Nailed it! I thought a delegate would do it, just didn't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you’re sure your main problem is MethodInfo.Invoke…

Use stuff from System.Linq.Expressions (Expression.Call, Expression.Parameter) to create an expression that calls that MethodInfo method, passing your parameters for instance + arguments.

Compile that expression into `Action<tInstance, tArgs[]>` (don't know your types of these).

Cache that Action in your CallInfo class instance.

Invoke that action as needed.

Comment: The key here is to create a `Delegate` to do successive calls; using reflection or expressions or whatever to create one, does not really matter.

Comment: @soonts: Yes, I'm aware of that path but never tried it. Action<> is just a delegate, isn't it?

Comment: @thehennyy: create delegate from MethodInfo but not by Expressions? How? Is that worth an answer?

Comment: @david.pfx There is a `Delegate.CreateDelegate` overload that takes a `MethodInfo` as target. Depending on you use-case you probably have to do a `DynamicInvoke`, but that is not as fast as a direct call. A way around that would be to create a closure with the parameters to use, with `Reflection.Emit` or `Expressions` and call that with a parameterless `Action` delegate. -- There are a lot of possibilities with code generation, but if they are worth the pain depends on your needs.

Comment: @thehennyy: see edit. It has to be an instance method call, which rules out delegates (I think).

Comment: @david.pfx You need this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343914(v=vs.110).aspx As you see, it accepts an expression for the instance to call your method on. Pass a ParameterExpression there, and you’ll be able to compile it into a delegate that accepts instance as a parameter.

Comment: @Soonts: yes, that looks like something I can try. Thanks.